# ¿Cómo guardar mediante un botón los datos ingresados?

Tags: java, android-sqlite, onclick

Cuando voy a emular la aplicación para guardar los datos ingresados en un botón llamado `botoninsertar`, me da este error:

> error: view.OnClickListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method onClick(View) in android.view.View.OnClickListener
>   ).

Este lo hice basado en la *API de Android*.

Pienso que podría ser por lo del `onClick` pero mi tutor no lo hizo así y le funcionó. Además cuando quiero agregar el método al *botón insertar* por medio del `onClick`, no me muestra la opción.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  Button botoninsertar,botonactualizar,botonborrar,botonbuscar;
  EditText textoid,textonombre,textoapellido;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    botoninsertar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insertar);
    botonactualizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.actualizar);
    botonborrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.borrar);
    botonbuscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buscar);

    textoid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id);
    textonombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre);
    textoapellido = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.apellido);

    final BBDD_Helper helper = new BBDD_Helper(this);

    botoninsertar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // Gets the data repository in write mode
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ESTRUCTURA_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA1,textoid.getText().toString());
        values.put(ESTRUCTURA_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA2,textonombre.getText().toString());
        values.put(ESTRUCTURA_BBDD.NOMBRE_COLUMNA3,textoapellido.getText().toString());

        // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
        long newRowId = db.insert(ESTRUCTURA_BBDD.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"se guardo el registro con clave: "+
        newRowId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    });
    botonborrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

      }
    });
    botonactualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
      }
    });
    botonbuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: _view onclick listener is not abstract and does not..._ ¿y qué más? Te ha faltado poner el error entero para intentar averiguar qué es lo que no le gusta. Incluye el error completo, por favor.

Comment: porque son tan estrictos en este foro?.con todo respeto esto es programacion no español,no quiero ser grosero disculpen

Comment: ¿Te ha parecido grosero preguntar por el error concreto que te da, que no habías especificado? Sin eso es complicado poder ayudarte. El error te está indicando que no reconoce la función `onClick` como la sobrecarga de la función de la clase base y que dado que tu clase no es abstracta, lo tienes que implementar. ¿Tienes otro `onClick` definido en tu clase `MainActivity`? Por alguna razón que no llego a detectar, esa función `onClick` no te la reconoce bien. Si te pido que expliques mejor tu pregunta no es por tocarte las narices, es por intentar entenderte y ayudarte.

Comment: ok disculpame.solo lo decia por las modificaciones pero agradezco lo que hacen